# CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue not returning expected value

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I've set my Dock to hide automatically:

```
host:~ user$ defaults read com.apple.dock autohide
1
```

This code, however, says otherwise:

```
Boolean hidesIsValid = false;
Boolean hides = CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue( CFSTR("autohide"),
                                                 CFSTR("com.apple.dock"),
                                                 &hidesIsValid );
```

`hidesIsValid` and `hides` are `false`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `CFPreferencesSynchronize( CFSTR("com.apple.dock"), kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost )` before trying to get the preference.  I read that starting with Mavericks, there is some new caching of preferences, hence the file contents are not always up to date.

Comment: @JWWalker: Still no luck. The result is still the same. I also tried variations with `kCFPreferencesCurrentHost`, just to be on the safe side.